# User Messaging Platform: Reset consent

Tags: android, admob, gdprconsentform, user-messaging-platform

As I read, GDPR requires consent to be revoked.

I only found the ConsentInformation.reset() method, but that one specifically mentions that it is only for debug purposes.

https://developers.google.com/admob/ump/android/api/reference/com/google/android/ump/ConsentInformation#public-abstract-void-reset

What is the correct way to withdraw consent so the Consent dialog gets shown again?

Answer (score -1):

Every time you call `form.show(act)` a dialog will be shown, even if the user already gave consent information. That's why you have to check if `consentInformation.consentStatus` has a value of `ConsentInformation.ConsentStatus.REQUIRED` before.

This all means that to provide the user a way of changing consent you just need to call `show(act)` without performing the check above.

Comment: Don't understand why this answer was accepted. It is not correct. You won't be able to load form if user already gave their consent. i.e. if status == OBTAINED then isConsentFormAvailable will return false, and if you try to load form it will fail with message "No available form can be built."